# iPhone Core Data how to add date sections to events with timestamps?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have two types of Events stored in my core data stack, each one having a timestamp. I'm interested if there's a good way to display these records in a `UITableView` with sections, where **each section is arbitrary long (a day, week, etc)**.

**Is there a way to convert a timestamp of a core data object into a section title, rounding down hours of the day?**

So we would get:

```
    October 5 < section title
    Record 1 < records displayed in the section
    Record 2
    Record 3

    October 6
    Record 4

    October 7 
    Record 5
    ...


-OR-
Week 1
Record 1
Record 2

Week 2
Record 3
...
```

Here's what I'm currently using to accomplish this goal, but it is limited to each section being a day.

But lets say that I have not thought about this requirement and have a list of events with just timestamps. How can I break them up into sections?

```
//the method used to convert a date into a number to store with the event
    -(int)getDateIDFromDate:(NSDate*)date
    {
        int gmtOffset =    [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
        int dateID =([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]+gmtOffset)/86400;
        return dateID;
    }


    //when inserting  a record, the number is saved
    newManagedObject.dayID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[self getDateIDFromDate:date]];


    //when retrieving, the number is used as a section key path
     NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"dayID" cacheName:@"Day"];


//the number gets converted back into the date.
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Display the authors' names as section headings.
        //    return [[[dataManager.dreamEventsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];

        NSString* dayIndex =  [[[dataManager.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] name];
        int dayFromReferenceDate = dayIndex.intValue;
        return [dataManager.sectionDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(dayFromReferenceDate+1)*86400]];



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding (redundant) data just for displaying purposes should always be a last resort.

In slightly similar cases, I just add a category to the CoreData object, e.g.

```
-(NSString*)firstLetter
{
    NSString *title = self.title;
    if ( [title length] == 0 ) return @"?";
    return [title substringToIndex:1];
}
```

then I just use this as the `sectionNameKeyPath` and all else is just the same as in a normal situation.

In your case, this category would be a little more elaborate, but the general outline could be the same. And the fact that section names will be volatile, should also be kept in mind.

A tricky (/ugly) part will be to communicate the current sectioning setting to the category. Some global or static variable could do the job efficiently.

Comment: This is a good idea. If I understand correctly, the firstLetter method would contain logic that I currently use to convert the date to a dayID and would return that.

Comment: I tried it out, and it did not work. THe first sort key for the NSFetchedResultsController must be the same as section name key path, and there's no such keypath. Without this, the app crashes as rows in  a section are not found. I tried adding a transient property, but don't think I did it correctly, as it was not possible to use it as a first sort descriptor

Comment: @AlexStone *"must be the same"* this is not a hard requirement. It has to be sorted according to the section name keypath, but not *using* the section name keypath. I.e. just sort using the actual date field, and add sections using the added field.

Comment: To be concrete: in the example above (from a real, working iOS app) the table is sorted using `title`, and has section names `firstLetter`. (which is good because most of the times you want the contents of each section to be sorted on that original field anyway)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to add a transient property to your managed object model. In that property's accessor, return a normalized `NSDate` with truncated hours (You can do this with `NSDateComponents`). Then when it's time to fetch those objects, set `.. sectionNameKeyPath:` to that transient property.

Updated: Let's say your NSManagedObject subclass had a transient attribute `monthOfTheYear`:

```
- (NSNumber*)monthOfTheYear
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"monthOfTheYear"];

    NSDateComponent *dateComponent = [cachedCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:self.timestamp]; // cachedCalendar is a NSCalendar instance

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"monthOfTheYear"];
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:dateComponent.month]; // or a normalized number that takes consideration of the year too
}
```

We don't create an NSString transient attribute directly because that will mess up your sorting (and you lose multi-language support).
The `willAccessValueForKey:` and `didAccessValueForKey:` are important. You should read more on their documentations.

Then when it's time to display the section titles:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger monthNumber = // Get the monthOfTheYear value from the first NSManagedObject in this section.
    return [[cachedDateFormatter monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(monthNumber-1)]; // cachedDateFormatter is a NSDateFormatter instance

}
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit more detail on how to create an accessor for this property? I tried putting it in the core data subclass, after @dynamic titleForSection; -(NSString*)titleForSection{...} , but this did not work

Answer (score 0):

Sup bro! my advice would be to use NSDateFormatter

This is the link for Apple documentation: [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I would add a category on the managedObject where you have the timeStamp,

```
@interface MyManagedobject (ReadableTimestamp)
     -(NSString *)formatedStringFromTimestamp;
@end 

@implementation MyManagedobject (ReadableTimestamp)
     -(NSString *)formatedStringFromTimestamp{
        //TODO: Here you apply all your fancy format, I'm just using the default
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [formatter setDateStyle:dateStyle];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:timeStyle];
         NSString *result = [formatter stringForObjectValue:self.timestamp];
        return result;
     }

 @end
```

I hope this helps, good times.

If you're some kind of an optimization freak (like myself) you can define your timeFormatter as an static so that you don't need to build it everytime.